# CUDA: Does the compute capability impact the maximum number of active threads?

Tags: cuda

If I have a device supporting CC 3.0 that means it has maximum number of active threads equal to 2048 per multiprocessor. And If would set the CC to 2.0 (compute_20,sm_20) does it mean that the maximum number of active threads will be only 1536 per multiprocessor or the compute capability has no impact to this?

Or is it have impact to the shared memory size?

Comment: Are you trying to compare GPUs of different compute capabilities, or asking what happens if you compile a kernel for compute_20 but run it on a GPU of compute capability 3.0? (or something else?)

Comment: I mean, what happens if I compile a kernel for compute_20 on device supporting compute capability 3.0, does it reduce the number of max active threads per multiprocessor or it has nothing to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

CUDA is designed for scalability; kernels will expand to use all of the resources it can. So it doesn't matter how you compile the kernel; it will fill up all of the available threads unless you do something that prevents it from doing so, like launching it with 768 threads per block.

Now, GPU threads aren't like CPU cores; you aren't losing the ability to do computation if you aren't using all of the threads. A streaming multiprocessor (SM) on a device of compute capability 3.0 can manage 2048 threads simultaneously, but is only capable of executing 256 instructions per tick. There are other limits too; e.g. if you're doing 32-bit floating point addition, it can only do 192 of those per tick. Doing left shifts on 32-bit integers? Only 64 per tick.

The point of having more threads is for latency reasons -- when one thread is blocked for some reason, such as waiting to fetch a value from memory or to get the result of an arithmetic instruction, the SM will run a different thread instead. The point of using more threads is that it gives you more opportunities to hide this latency: more chances to have independent work available to do when some instructions are blocked, waiting for data.